# Java-How to start an AsyncTask from another AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have two `AsyncTask` classes, `ConnectionThread` and `CommunicationThread`. I am trying to make `ConnectionThread` create and execute CommunicationThreads inside its `onPostExecute` in a while loop, like this:

```
protected synchronized void onPostExecute(Thread2ThreadInfo info) {
                while (true) {
                    CommunicationThread commThread = new CommunicationThread();
                    commThread.execute(info);
                    try {
                        this.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
                }

        }
```

What I am doing is create a CommunicationThread `commThread` and execute it. After that I make the current `ConnectionThread` wait.

In the `ConnectionThread` I do some stuff in `doInBackground` and then call `notifyAll` to wake the `communicationThread` that executed this `connectionThread`. The code of `ConnectionThread` is:

```
protected synchronized Value doInBackground(Thread2ThreadInfo... info) {
            //Do some stuff    
            notifyAll();
            Log.e("start", "after notify");

        }
```

Although, `notifyAll` is executed a the communicationThread is not waking up and the program freezes there. How should I use `wait` and `notify` to achieve this behavior ?

Comment: can you attach notifyAll() function? your question is so vague. both of the codes above are belong to one class, so write it in one block. your question is so confusing. attach the full code for better understanding the problem.